# How can I do inplace editing (-i) with perl on windows?

Tags: windows, perl, inplace-editing

In the unix/linux version, I'd simply change the first line:

```
#!perl -i.bak
```

Using Activestate perl on windows, where I've created the association with .pl, I can run a perl script directly from the command line.

```
myScript.pl
```

How can I do inplace editing of files if I still want to use the default association?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a trick question, and I wonder if I am understanding you right.

```
perl -pi.bak myScript.pl myfiletochange
```

Just call perl, supply the switches and the script name, and off you go.

Now, it may be that you do not want to supply these extra arguments. If so, you can simply set [the variable `$^I`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5EI), which will activate the inplace edit. E.g.:

```
$^I = ".bak"; # will set backup extension
```

Comment: No trick - creating a script for a non-technical user, and would like to have it self-contained.  Thanks.

Comment: @chris Your non-technical user should be aware that while the script saves a backup, that backup is overwritten for each subsequent use of the script on the source file.

Comment: They all say it's a one-time thing. :)

Comment: @chris It's only a one-time thing until the next time. =P

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to be using a script you might want to do something like this:

```
sub edit_in_place
{
    my $file       = shift;
    my $code       = shift;
    {
        local @ARGV = ($file);
        local $^I   = '';
        while (<>) {
            &$code;
        }
    }
}

edit_in_place $file, sub {
    s/search/replace/;
    print;
};
```

if you want to create a backup then change `local $^I = '';` to `local $^I = '.bak';`